Could not figure out where the code to mutate is. Please specify it on the command line using --paths-to-mutate
This is my folder structure
I'm trying to run mutation tests with MutMut for a Python project, but I keep getting the error:
FileNotFoundError: Could not figure out where the code to mutate is. Please specify it on the command line using --paths-to-mutate, or by adding "paths_to_mutate=code_dir" in setup.cfg to the [mutmut] section.
My setup.cfg file:
\[mutmut\]

paths_to_mutate=app/

runner=python -m pytest ./tests/is_prime_tests.py

tests_dir=tests/

Steps I've tried:

Verified that the directory app/ exists and contains the Python source code to be mutated.

Checked that pytest works by running python -m pytest ./tests/is_prime_tests.py, and all tests passed successfully.

Ran python -m mutmut run but got the same FileNotFoundError.

Tried specifying the path to mutate directly using:
python -m mutmut run --paths-to-mutate=app/
But Still got the same error.
Environment:

Windows 11

Python 3.11.0

MutMut 3.1.0

pytest 8.3.3


I've double-checked the folder structure and paths but can't figure out why MutMut is unable to find the code to mutate. Any ideas on how to fix this?


